# Symfony2 - Sort Multi-dimensional Array Recursive

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My FAQ-System is able to have SubFAQ's, every FAQ and SubFAQ can be liked (likecount).

I managed to sort all FAQ's (parents) by the likecount in my Controller with:

```
        $faqs = $this->getDoctrine()// DATENBANK LADEN UND DIREKT SORTIEREN
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Faq')
        ->findBy(array('parent' => null), array('likecount' => 'desc'));
```

The problem is, that the SubFAQ's are still not sorted by the likecount.

**Dump for Parents (FAQ)**

```
  "faqs" => array:13 [▼
0 => Faq {#1025 ▼
  -id: 23
  -question: "ajaja"
  -answer: "ajaja"
  -username: "Robert"
  -userid: 1
  -createdat: DateTime {#1023 ▶}
  -likecount: 4
  -tags: PersistentCollection {#1040 ▶}
  -categoryid: Category {#1015 ▶}
  -children: PersistentCollection {#1042 ▶}
  -parent: null
  -faqcatid: Category {#1015 ▶}
```

**Dump for Children (SubFAQ)**

```
    0 => Faq {#1349 ▼
  -id: 72
  -question: "1"
  -answer: "1"
  -username: "Robert"
  -userid: 1
  -createdat: DateTime {#1351 ▶}
  -likecount: null
  -tags: PersistentCollection {#1095 ▶}
  -categoryid: null
  -children: PersistentCollection {#1372 ▶}
  -parent: Faq {#469 ▶}
  -faqcatid: null
```

I include a *'subfaq.html.twig'* in every FAQ and passing him the children. It includes itself again in the subfaq.html.twig, in case there are Subs in Subs.

```
{{ include('default/subfaq.html.twig', {'faqs' : faq.children}) }}
```

How could I solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [order associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html) using annotation:

```
/** @Entity **/
class Faq
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="SubFaq")
     * @OrderBy({"likecount" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $subfaqs;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Working!